# void-function lexical-let

Tags: microsoft-windows, lexical-scoping

I'm using this code on Xubuntu (emacs 24.5.1) but it throw error on windows (emacs 25.0.50.1 64bit)

```
(defun ignore-error-wrapper (fn)
  "Funtion return new function that ignore errors.
   The function wraps a function with `ignore-errors' macro."
  (lexical-let ((fn fn))
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (ignore-errors
        (funcall fn)))))

(global-set-key [s-left] (ignore-error-wrapper 'windmove-left))
(global-set-key [s-right] (ignore-error-wrapper 'windmove-right))
(global-set-key [s-up] (ignore-error-wrapper 'windmove-up))
(global-set-key [s-down] (ignore-error-wrapper 'windmove-down))
```

Comment: Please include some description of the error that is signaled.  My crystal ball says that the problem is that you use `lexical-let` without first requiring `cl` (which is the package that exports `lexical-let`).

Comment: @Stefan FWIW the error (void-function lexical-let) was mentioned in the title of the question. (But I do think it is very confusing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lexical-let` is defined in `cl.el`. You can `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` to fix the problem. This is mostly equivalent to `(require 'cl)` but is more efficient when you byte-compile your code (see Drew's comment below).

Comment: `cl-lib` is preferred to `cl`. To quote the CL manual: "New code should use cl-lib rather than cl." Ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Organization.html#Organization

Comment: But `cl-lib` doesn't define `lexical-let`, so it's a bit less interesting for the problem at hand. I think the preferred way would be to rewrite the code with lexical-binding turned on.

Comment: You are correct. I assumed that `cl-lib` provided `lexical-let`, but I was wrong.

Comment: Nope. You do not need to (and should not, since you do not need to), require `cl.el` at *runtime*. `lexical-let` is a **macro** (defined in `cl.el`), so what you should do is **`(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))`**.